# Configure Charles proxy on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, google-chrome, proxy

I installed **Charles proxy v4.2.1** on Ubuntu 16.04 for listening requests from Chrome browser & my android device plugged to the computer. Instead of automatic configuring like it works on Windows & MacOS, my Charles proxy didn't listen anything without configuration in default. I followed some posts telling the way to configure Charles. That's about configuring SSL, IP, importing/adding certification,.... However, both of them didn't help Charles works properly, it still listened nothing.

I think I missed any step when configuring my Charles app. Could you help me list necessary steps to achieve the configuration?

Many thanks.

Comment: https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/configuration/

Comment: I followed that, but it didn't work, though.

Comment: *I think I missed any step when configuring my Charles app. Could you help me list necessary steps to achieve the configuration?* i.e. you asked for the list and I gave it in the comment above. Now you say you followed it ergo you didn't miss a step (according to you, that is). How can we possibly help you? A better idea: [edit] your question and describe *exactly* what you did, what were the expected results and what happened instead? Post error messages and screenshots if pertinent.